# Low Search - Pagination

Tags: low-search

Does Low Search support the support the "P" suffix of native pagination of {exp:channel:entries}?

For example, if i have this url

```
test.com/search/jcg4uv8e9w4n09wn0v034mnv09j34ov3459j49g/P4
```

Does it go to the corresponding page(in this case, page 4)?

If not, then how should it handle it?

EDIT:

I tried using [paginate_base](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#paginate-base) but when I used it, the query segment with the long string won't show in the url. The query segment is generated by [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/).

```
test.com/search/P4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PXX` is the offset of the total results & the limit set within the tag. So if you set a `limit=20` in the `low_search:results` tag, page 4 would be `P80`. `low_search:results` acts just like the `channel:entries` tag, so you can use any of those [parameters](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters) to tweak your pagination.

```
{exp:low_search:results 
   query="{segment_2}" 
   limit="20"
   paginate="bottom"
   status="not closed"
   disable="categories|member_data"
}
```

Comment: So basically the number in PXX is the limit offset?

Comment: Correct. There is a few addons that replace the native pagination links. __Better Pagination__ http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-pagination

Comment: Does Better Pagination work with Low Search?

Comment: Not sure, you would have to try it out.